# Meteor crashing after update - A route for the path already exists by the name

Tags: linux, meteor, iron-router, fibers

Hi SO community I have this application and after I did the upgrade to the most recent version of meteor (1.3) the application fails uppon start.

```
/home/ec2-user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.0_3.fc5itk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: A route for the path "/oauth/authorize" already exists by the name of "oauth.authorize".
 at Iron.utils.assert (packages/iron_core.js:66:11)
 at Function.Router.route (packages/iron_router.js:745:3)
 at meteorInstall.server.native-routes.coffee (server/native-routes.coffee:1:8)
 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9)
 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
 at /home/ec2-user/oauth/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:1002:1
 at /home/ec2-user/oauth/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
 at Array.forEach (native)
 at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ec2-user/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.0_3.fc5itk++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
 at /home/ec2-user/oauth/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
```

the output shows this error like 4 times (it looks like meteor is trying to run 5 times the same route files)

I tried to give a name to all routes, but doesn't work

I hope I can receive any help

Have a nice day

Comment: Does the application import another Oauth module? Looks like a collision.